# Raspberry Pi with touchscreen - screen turns white and pi restarts when trying to use LEDs

Tags: pi-3b+, led, troubleshooting

We currently have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with touchscreen hooked up to a PCB, and are trying to run adafruit neopixel 60led strip but, when we try and send data using their library, the screen turns white and the pi restarts. We've tried hooking up a different Pi, but the same problem continues. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: @Dougie Thanks for the help. After some investigation, our electrical guy determined that when the pin is turned on, there's a capacitor that is drawing too much power from the pi and causing it to restart. We do have an external power supply but it's voltage is too low apparently. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blowing the power budget. You need an external power supply for your LED strip.

You're lucky you haven't trashed your SDCard by losing the power supply when the system is busy.